# Difference between ほとんどのX and Xのほとんど

Tags: grammar

I'm used to seeing ほとんどのX to mean 'most X'. Sometimes I see Xのほとんど like in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/how-is-this-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9-used). Are both forms equally valid? do they have exactly the same meaning? For example is there any difference between the following:

> ほとんどの果物は丸い。
>   果物のほとんどは丸い。
>   Most fruits are round.

Edit: I'm failing to see how this is a duplicate of a question I already added a link to. If I'm missing something please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this ほとんど used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52847/how-is-this-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%a8%e3%82%93%e3%81%a9-used)

Comment: ^ でもそのリンクされたスレッドには、「Xのほとんどが/は」「Xもほとんどが」の説明はありますけど、「ほとんどのX」は出てきませんし説明も比較もされてないですよね・・

Comment: It seems to me ”ほとんどの果物は丸い” implies that you have actually seen many fruits and most of them are round.Then you conclude "Most fruits are round". On the other hand, "果物のほとんどは丸い。" implies that since the data provides 95% of fruits in the world are round, you conclude "Most fruits are round".

Comment: @kimiTanaka I think your example nicely matches with the conclusion of the accepted answer. That helps. Thanks.

Comment: 「ほとんどのリンゴを食べた」は "I ate most apples" って感じですけど「リンゴのほとんどを食べた」は "I ate most apples" とも "I ate most part of an apple" ともとれるような気がします。。　ところで「ほとんどの人は～」「ほとんどの場合は～」はいいですが、「人のほとんどは～」「場合のほとんどは～」は変ですよね。なんででしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate ほとんどを先に使うと、その次のXを単数名詞として扱うという事でしょうか。Xを先に持ってくるとXが単数・集合どちらでも使えないかといけないという事でしょうか。人は微妙ですけど、場合を集合的に扱うのは変ですね。

Comment: @Chocolate つまり、「ほとんどのリンゴを食べた」の場合は先にリンゴ一個一個を食べていって、その後でリンゴの全体（箱に詰まったたくさんのリンゴなど）を思い浮かべてリンゴの大部分を食べたという事、一方「リンゴのほとんどを食べた」の場合は、先にリンゴの全体を用意して（箱に詰まったたくさんのリンゴ、単にリンゴ一個そのもの）その大部分を食べるという事でしょうか。

Comment: ＠Chocolate 「場合のほとんど～」がおかしく思えるのは「場合」の中に何が入っているかが分かりづらいですよね。「人」は「人類」を指せば全人類から、個々人に向かっていくから「人（人類）のほとんどは定住生活を送る」はそこまで変じゃないかな。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would indeed be tempting to say that these two constructions are effectively one and the same, but there are some instances where you simply cannot use them interchangeably. The subtle nuances are easier to grasp when they are translated into English.

> [Grammatical]: **ほとんどの**果物は丸い。
>
> = **Most** fruits are round. [adjective-ish]
>
> [Grammatical]: 果物**のほとんど**は丸い。
>
> = Fruits are **almost always** / **in most cases** round. [adverb-ish]

---

With this in mind, let's take a look at the following example:

> [Grammatical]: ... その原因**のほとんどは**運転手のミスである。
>
> = They are **almost always** / **in most cases** caused by ... [adverb-ish]

In this specific instance though, you cannot switch the words around and use the adjective-ish construction ほとんどのX:

> [NOT grammatical]: **ほとんどの**その原因は運転手のミスである。
>
> = **Most their** causes are ... [adjective-ish]

It is the word その [its/that/their] that makes this adjective-ish construction impossible here.

Bear with me here, as I have intentionally used clumsy English phrasing "most their causes are" for the sake of better capturing the feel of the Japanese sentence.

Comment: This answer seems very clear and convincing to me. Why the lack of upvotes?

Comment: @user3856370 Hi. It might be a good idea to convert the *adverb-ish* "Xのほとんどは" into "Xはほとんど" or "Xはほとんどの場合、": "果物**のほとんどは**丸い" = "果物**はほとんど**丸い" and "その原因**のほとんどは**運転手のミスである" = "その原因**はほとんどの場合、** 運転手のミスである"

Comment: 「その原因はほとんど**が**運転手のミスである」「果物はほとんど**が**丸い」でもいいですよね・・・

Comment: @Chocolate I don't know what to do now. I'm guessing my question is very difficult to answer. Do you believe the accepted answer is wrong and could you explain why please? For example, is 果物のほとんどは丸い actually ungrammatical, and is the problem about the order of 果物 and ほとんど or is it about making 果物のほとんど a sentence topic?

Comment: @user3856370 I don't think the accepted answer is wrong (I'm not the downvoter, btw)... I just don't know what would be the *right* answer, to be honest. I think 果物のほとんどは丸い is grammatically fine. And I think it has the same meaning as ほとんどの果物は丸い. I think you could also say it as 果物はほとんどが丸い.

Comment: @user3856370 (cont.) `I'm guessing my question is very difficult to answer.` そうかもしれませんね・・・＾＾ I think リンゴのほとんどを食べた could have a different meaning from ほとんどのリンゴを食べた... (though they can mean the same thing, too, of course) and, ほとんどの人は～、ほとんどの場合は～ sound okay but 人のほとんどは～、場合のほとんどは～ sound unnatural to me (but why?)

Comment: @Chocolate: 「果物」「運転」と違って「人」「場合」の違和感は本当ですね。考えてみました。語り手は自分の考えがまずあり、それを言葉で伝えるので気にしませんが、聞き手は違います。受け取る言葉の一つ一つで語り手の考えを描いて（絞って）いきます。最初に「ほとんど」と聞いた場合と「人」と聞いた場合とでは、「ほとんど」では迷いはありません。次の言葉を待たずに意味が決定しております。一方、「人」と聞いた場合オプションがあり過ぎです。「ほとんどの人」では、「人」と聞いたところで意味はほぼつかめます。「人のほとんど」と聞いた場合は、「ほとんど」でも安心できず、どんな「人」か悩みます。人類かな、その辺の人々かな、それとも「一人の人」かな。「人のほとんど」では意味を絞るために更に次の言葉を待たなければなりません。実は私たちはそんなに頭が良くないので、ずっと前の単語の意味を確定するのに後続する単語をいくつも待てません。従って、次々と意味が確定していく表現がちゃんとある場合は、そうでない表現に対して違和感があるのではないでしょうか。「人」「場合」は「果物」「運転」に比べてのオプションの多過ぎが原因ではないですか。